# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function in Parse-React App

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-react

I am building a Parse-React-Ratchet App and I am running into an unfamiliar error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function" in the browser console. The error message is rooted in class-call-check.js in the node-module babel-runtime. I am attempting to create a list of businesses that are of a specific business category. The business category is stored as a pointer in the business table like this (Pseudocode)

Business {name, phone, category}

The components observe function looks like this

```
observe(props,state){
  return{
     businesses: new Parse.Query('Business').equalTo('category',  Parse.Object('_BusinessCategory', { objectId: this.props.categoryId}))
  }
}
```

I am passing the category Id from a BusinessList component like this

```
<div className="content">
   <BusinessList categoryId={this.props.categoryId}/>
</div>
```

Which itself is being passed the categoryId from its parent like this

```
router.addRoute('categories/:id', function(id) {
        this.setState({page: <CategoryPage categoryId={id}/>});
    }.bind(this));
```

in the parents componentDidMount function. I suspect that my query is not written correctly considering I am trying to access a pointer in the query filter

Thank u in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: It is because Parse.Query returns a class not a function...